# Regular Expressions and Variables

Tags: regex

I am new with working with regular expressions. While I understand most of the basics, I am curious about ways to extract variables out of a regular expression. I have tried googling it but I come short each time.

What I am trying to do is parse out an arbitrary number of string words out of a line of regex. The length or general sytax is undefined to my parser. The delimeter between each word is also unknown. Linux Bash scripting uses ${variablename}

Examples:
User Defined RegEx:
"*[a-zA-Z0-9]*${variable1}*.**${variable2}*...*([0-9]+)_${variable3}"

I want the user to define the regex of the string I am going to parse out. I want them to set which items are the variables that I care about. I can verify later that an input string matches this regex, and then pull out anything flagged as ${} as a variable. 
Later, once my program has received the user defined regex above, it will begin to take String inputs:

"_hello12_world_randomjunk12345$#!_wide_123_96584_web"
this input will match the regex and I will be able to pull out:
world as variable1
wide as variable2
web as variable3

My actual question: Does regex have a general syntax that handles variables inside a regex instead of the ${} that I have written above? ${} is a bash scripting thing and I can create it in my program if I have to, I just want to make sure I am not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using? What programming environment is this in? Named capturing groups seem to be what you're after.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a convention for a placeholder for a variable in a regex string? If so, the answer is no.

Comment: I am using the regex engine in java at the moment. Other engines can be a consideration if they prove to have additional functionality. Thanks MikeM, that might answer my question. I will probably end up RegEx'ing the RegEx pattern supplied and create my own sort of protocol for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

In RegEx the pieces you want to extract are known as Groups and are identified by surrounding the appropriate portion of your expression with parentheses.

From there, the way you extract and use those values will depend entirely on your language/library but searching Groups should give you what you are after.

Comment: In re-reading this post I am not sure now if you are asking about accessing parts of the match or using variables in the actual building of the expression.  Please clarify and I will delete my response if not appropriate.

Comment: Variables in the actual building of the expression. The idea is my code will read in the regex provided by the user - lets say in Java. In my example above, my code will see that there are 3 variables in the regex, so it will create String variable1, String variable2, String variable3. Then when the actual string comes through, it will put whatever exists in the spot of variable1 into the String variable1.